# Serializing an array in C#

Tags: c#, serialization

I always find very sophisticated way to serialize all kind of objects, lists and who knows,
But I can't seem to find a simple way to serialize an array.

(I found **one**, but its serializing the array to a binary file, and I need to be able to edit the serialized file in any regular text editor [It's a language file, I need to give copies to my co-workers so they can translate the file into other languages/])

Comment: Uhm,... you need it to be human-readable? Why not use JSON-like syntax for the serialization? Or XML?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming your array is an array of strings...

```
using (var stream = File.Create("file.xml")) {
    var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(string[]));
    serializer.Serialize(stream, someArrayOfStrings);
}
```

Will create a simple XML file that is very easy to understand/modify. To deserialize it, use the Deserialize method.

Comment: Can you bring an example of deserializtion?

Answer (score 6):

Human readable? I'd go for JavaScriptSerializer; just:

```
string json = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(arr);
```

Answer (score 2):

> It's a language file, I need to give
>   copies to my co-workers so they can
>   translate the file into other language

XML Serialization is ideal it sounds like based on the above statement

Answer (score 2):

If the serialized array needs to be portable and editable in a text editor, then you can use XML or Json to serialize

Answer (score 1):

best way to learn is look at how it's done with a xsd that serialize into a xml

[starting point](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx)